# Does uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt auto reconnect client when disconnected?

Tags: c#, mqtt

I am using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt version 4.3.0 as a client to pub/sub a message. I want to make sure that the client auto reconnects when the connection is lost or the client is disconnected. Does uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt supports auto reconnection after the failure of connection to MQTT broker?.
I have made a research but could not get better solution of it

Comment: One problem, one question, there are at least 2 separate questions here.

Comment: Also what makes you think that library has been updated to support MQTT v5? It was last updated 3 years ago (really more like 6 years ago) https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/issues/130

Comment: Well, the main question is to know either it is able to auto-reconnect when the client disconnected due to some failure or should i do it manaully. I am updating my question and will add a new one to ask another

Comment: I think it doesnt , there is a PR with the auto reconnect feature catching dust in the repo . If you are capable of pulling the changes and figuring out the steps : https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/pull/91 . It hasn't gone to upstream yet and the repo looks untouched from 3 years, so its highly unlikely.